# What should say the isoperimetric inequality for taxicab geometry?

Tags: geometry, inequality, reference-request

It seems that there is literature for this topic,

> **Question.** What should say the isoperimetric inequality for taxicab geometry? Have you got any idea? Then you tell us some easy facts or idea about this. Thanks in advance.

I've tried read about this geometry, and previous topic. In this geometry $4$ is $\pi$!, but still I have no idea about previous question.

The statement of the isoperimetrical inequality that I refer to you is in first paragraph of [1], and a reference for the Taxicab gometry is [2]. Yoo I've found nice sites about conics in this geometry, for example ellipses. Another relates quadrilaterals.

**References:**

[1] Wikipedia, Isoperimetric inequality  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isoperimetric_inequality

[2] Wikipedia, Taxicab geometry https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_geometry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best possible ratio is from the unit square, with perimeter $4$ and area $1$, as adding any other square increases $A$ by $1$ and $P$ by at most $2$, so we have:

$$\dfrac{P}{A}-\dfrac{P+2}{A+1}=\dfrac{P-2A}{A(A+1)}\ge0$$

if we start from  the unit square.

We also only need consider convex regions as concave regions merely increase $P$ and decrease $A$, and we can note that a convex region has the same perimeter as a bounding rectangle.

As $\large{\pi_{\small TC}}=4$, we have $4{\large\pi_{\small TC}} A\le P^2
$, with equality iff the shape is a square.

We can define a concave region as having a larger perimeter than the bounding rectangle, which is equivalent to some row or column having $4+$ edges present.

Comment: Thanks @JonMarkPerry I will read your answer. Now I vote up.